# Django multiple databases ... all models are created in second db despite router, is my router not good?

Tags: django, django-models

Django 2.2.18

I want to split the models of one app to a second database. The relevant app is named "dear_zoho_analytics", which I assume is the 'app_label'.
The original database is "default".

I have only one dbrouter, and it has code like this:

```
class DbRouter(object):
    
    route_app_labels = ["dear_zoho_analytics", ]
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        .
        .
        .


    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
      
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == "dear_analytics"
        return None
```

when I do this:

`python3 ./manage.py migrate  --database=dear_analytics`

I get the tables of every app created in the new database.

`python3 ./manage.py migrate dear_zoho_analytics --database=dear_analytics`
does what I want. However, this sort of implies that my allow migrate is not working because it appears to do nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to return False if the app_label is not "dear_zoho_analytics" when the db is "dear_analytics":

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        if db != "dear_analytics":
            return False
        return True
    elif db == "dear_analytics":
        return False
    return None
```

I have assumed you want this apps tables only in the "dear_analytics" db. Otherwise you may have to modify conditions a little.

Answer (score 1):

Your routing ensures that `dear_zoho_analytics` app is routed to `dear_analytics`, for rest of apps they are routed to all databases

simply adding additional condition would ensure other apps not being migrated to second database

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return db ==  "dear_analytics"
    else:
        return db != "dear_analytics"
```